# Reindexing for summation calculation

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

I would like to know if $\displaystyle \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} i^2 = \sum_{i=2}^{n} (i-1)^2$

I feel my way of re-indexing makes sense, however, the computer shows me two different results.

The answer for $\displaystyle \sum_{i=3}^{n-1} i^2 = \frac{1}{6}(2n^3-3n^2+n-30)$. However, for $\displaystyle  \sum_{i=3}^{n} (i-1)^2$, it euqals to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{6}(2n^3-3n^2+n-6)$

So if what I do is right, why there are two different answers?
If it is wrong, where have I made a mistake? And what should I do?

**PS: I am trying to do the reindexing because I want to use existing formula to facilitate my calculation (as required on the exam): $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^ni^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$**

Comment: The left hand starts at $2^2$, the right hand starts at $1^2$.

Comment: But if I remove 1^2, the two results still won't be equal

Comment: Yes, they will.  See, e.g., [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%28i-1%29%5E2%2C%7Bi%2C2%2Cn%7D%5D-sum%5Bi%5E2%2C%7Bi%2C2%2Cn-1%7D%5D)

Comment: Thanks! I was not thinking about my lower limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What would be correct re-indexing is $\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}i^2=\sum_{i=3}^n(i-1)^2$ or $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2=\sum_{i=2}^n(i-1)^2$.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that I have to pay attention to the lower limit as well, I was not thinking about that! Thank you for pointing this out!